# How to make logo stay centered and shrink to fit as browser resized

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design, genesis

Trying here: http://alternativegrow.com.au/

to make logo stay centered and shrink to fit as browser resized (instead of getting cut off). I have followed a number of recommended techniques but to no avail...

I am a little unsure which elements I've added or modified are helping or hindering.

What I've added, via custom css plug in for now:

```
    .header-image .site-title > a {
    float: left;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-size: 100% auto !important;
    background-position:center; 
}

    .title-area {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.site-header .wrap {
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

What is in stylesheet:

```
/* ## Title Area
--------------------------------------------- */

.title-area {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 15px;
    width: 360px;
}

.header-full-width .title-area {
    width: 100%;
}

.site-title {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.2;
}

.site-title a,
.site-title a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

 .header-image .site-title > a {
    background: url(images/logo.png) no-repeat left;
    float: left;
    min-height: 160px;
    width: 350px;
} 

.site-description {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

.site-description,
.site-title {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.header-image .site-description,
.header-image .site-title {
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}

.site-description {
    color: #fff;
```

edit - Oh I did try media queries but they also did not work. Specifically I tried adjusting the min-height at different beak points, with width set as auto, expecting the width to adjust relative to the height setting, but in fact the logo just disappeared when I did this. I do not really want to use multiple sized logos for various break points as this seems clunky to me, however it is better than what is here, but this also did not work for me.

Comment: you can set the width and the height of logo to a %, it will make it shrink. To make it centered after the % you can use margin-left:auto and margin-right: auto

Comment: Thank you @sinanspd but clearly I am not implementing your suggestions correctly as yet. I have the height & width set at 100% and the argin-left:auto and margin-right: auto as per your suggestion in the `.header-image .site-title > a` rule but to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure to understand whether the example you point to is what you try to achieve or what you try to modify.

Maybe this [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogJRJw) can help you

The important parts are:

1) to make the element which holds the logo as background take all the space available

2) set the background-size at 'contain'

```
<header>
  <div class="logo"></div>
</header>

.logo{
  background:url('http://www.vectortemplates.com/raster/batman-logo-big.gif') no-repeat center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size:contain;
}

header{
 height:200px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @laurent, yes the example you have given me is exactly what I want. The example I have shown is what needs changing. I am not clear on how to implement this change within the structure that exists. For example, if you use firebug or whatever you can see that on my site there are two sets of entries (below). The first set are my changes in custom css plugin the second are in the stylesheet.
`.header-image .site-title > a {
    background-size: contain;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.header-image .site-title > a {
    float: left;
    min-height: 160px;
}`

Comment: To be clear the only issue I have with the current logo behaviour on my website is the way the logo does not resize when you get down to the skinniest widths. 320, 240 etc

Comment: Actually the problem comes from your .wrap element which does not resize. set its width at 100% instead of 400px. And then don't forget to set the background-position to center for you logo. You'll have to set the padding to same value for your .title-area as well (otherwise you will get an offset)